# Removing external drive safely in Fedora21

Tags: fedora

Using previous posts, I used the following command in fedora21 terminal to remove the external drive safely:

```
# umount full_path_to_external_drive
```

When I checked with the command `df -k`, the external looked removed, but  its icon was seen in the desktop. If I clicked that icon, the external drive again got mounted. How can I remove the external drive safely in fedora21?

Comment: Presumably, clicking the icon remounts the drive...

Comment: You may be interested in udisksctl. It makes a distinction between unmounting and "powering off" a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Once you `umount`, it is indeed "safely removed".

But, as your hard-drive is still physically attached to your computer, you can still see it. If you do a `lsblk`, you'll see that there isn't a mount point for it (or if there is, your drive could have been mounted on several places...).

While it's still plugged (but not necessarily mounted), you should also see it listed with `lsusb`.

So, short answer : you can unplug your drive once you `umount` it.